# Django-postgres-extra package ENGIN error (table Partitioning)

Tags: django, postgresql, partitioning, archive, django-postgresql

i have  two large tables in my database that change every day at 6AM , and I want to archive the most recent month  , i decided to use table partitioning to store every day's data in partition , i installed `django-postgres-extra` and i'm getting this error when i run the server
note that :

- i have two databases one for users , and the other one 'prev' for my app
- the tables that I want to archive are in prev
- I'm using the extension PostGis on 'prev'

**can you help me please ?**

here is my settings.py :

```
 > DATABASES = {
>     'default':{
>     },
>     'prev': {
>         'ENGINE':'psqlextra.backend',
>         'NAME': '[database_name]',
>         'USER':  '[username]',
>         'PASSWORD': '[Password]',
>         'HOST': 'localhost',
>     },
>     'users': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
>         'NAME':'[database_name]',
>         'USER': '[username]',
>         'PASSWORD':  '[Password]',
>         'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
>
```

> ```
> } } POSTGRES_EXTRA_DB_BACKEND_BASE = 'django.contrib.db.backends.postgis'
> ```
>
> DATABASE_ROUTERS=['user.router.AuthRouter' ,'prevision.router.PrevRouter']

error :

```
  $ python manage.py  runserver 
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
        raise _exception[1]
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
        autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psqlextra/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .base import PostgresModel
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psqlextra/models/base.py", line 6, in <module>
        class PostgresModel(models.Model):
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psqlextra/models/base.py", line 13, in PostgresModel
        objects = PostgresManager()
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psqlextra/manager/manager.py", line 23, in __init__
        [
      File "/home/user/Bureau/vig/backend/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psqlextra/manager/manager.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
        if "psqlextra" in db_settings["ENGINE"]
    KeyError: 'ENGINE'
```

**and if you have any other solution (package maybe) to solve the archiving problem please suggest it to me**

**Thank You .**

Comment: looks like two routers have problem, 'user.router.AuthRouter' ,'prevision.router.PrevRouter'